# How to scrape Google SERP using Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some Google search results. I followed several tutorials on the web, however I have the problem, that the results contain the "cookie box" that you first need to accept.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import re

urls = ["https://google.de/search?q=AL-KO Robolinho 110 preis",
        "https://google.de/search?q=AL-KO Robolinho 1150 W preis",
        "https://google.de/search?q=AL-KO Robolinho 300 E preis",
        "https://google.de/search?q=Yard Force X80i"]

fields = ["Price"]

with open('crawl-single-attribute/price.csv', 'w', newline="") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(fields)

    for url in urls:
        print('URL: ' + url)
        source = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        model = dict()

        print(soup)
```

And this is my result:

```
URL: https://google.de/search?q=AL-KO Robolinho 110 preis
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="de"><head><style nonce="5S2+IGx8vbOVCFxqR3V7gA">
//some css...
}
</style><title>Bevor Sie zur Google Suche weitergehen</title><meta content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5, width=device-width" name="viewport"/><link href="//www.google.com/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/></head><body><div class="signin"><a class="button" href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=de&amp;cd=DE&amp;continue=https://www.google.de/search?q%3DAL-KO%2520Robolinho%2520110%2520preis&amp;gae=cb-">Anmelden</a></div><div class="box"><img alt="Google" height="28" src="//www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_68x28dp.png" srcset="//www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_68x28dp.png 2x" width="68"/><div class="productLogoContainer"><img alt="" aria-hidden="true" class="image" height="100%" src="https://www.gstatic.com/ac/cb/scene_cookie_wall_search_v2.svg" width="100%"/></div><h1>Bevor Sie zur Google Suche weitergehen</h1><div class="contentText">Google verwendet <a href="https://policies.google.com/technologies/cookies?hl=de&amp;utm_source=ucb" target="_blank">Cookies</a> und Daten für Folgendes:<ul><li>Dienste anbieten und betreiben, z. B. Störungen prüfen und Maßnahmen gegen Spam, Betrug oder Missbrauch ergreifen</li><li>Daten zu Zielgruppeninteraktionen und Websitestatistiken erheben, um zu verstehen, wie unsere Dienste verwendet werden</li></ul>Wenn Sie zustimmen, verwenden wir Cookies und Daten auch für Folgendes:<ul><li>Qualität unserer Dienste verbessern und neue Dienste entwickeln</li><li>Werbung ausliefern und die Effektivität von Werbung messen</li><li>Personalisierte Inhalte anzeigen, abhängig von Ihren Einstellungen</li><li>Personalisierte oder allgemeine Werbung bei Google und im Web anzeigen, abhängig von Ihren Einstellungen</li></ul>Die Auswahl nicht personalisierter Inhalte und Werbeanzeigen kann davon abhängen, welche Inhalte Sie sich gerade ansehen und wo Sie sich befinden (die Anzeigenbereitstellung basiert auf dem allgemeinen Standort). Personalisierte Inhalte und Werbeanzeigen können ebenfalls darauf basieren, darüber hinaus aber auch auf Aktivitäten wie Suchanfragen bei Google und Videos, die Sie sich bei YouTube ansehen. Zu personalisierten Inhalten und Werbeanzeigen gehören beispielsweise Dinge wie relevantere Ergebnisse und Empfehlungen, eine individuelle YouTube-Startseite und Werbung, die auf Ihre Interessen zugeschnitten ist.<p>Klicken Sie auf „Anpassen“, um sich Ihre Möglichkeiten anzusehen. Zu diesen gehören zum Beispiel Steuerelemente, um Cookies für die Personalisierung zu deaktivieren, oder Informationen zu Steuerelementen auf Browserebene, mit denen einige oder alle Cookies für andere Zwecke deaktiviert werden können.  Besuchen Sie bei Bedarf jederzeit g.co/privacytools.</p></div><div><a class="button" href="https://consent.google.de/dl?continue=https://www.google.de/search?q%3DAL-KO%2520Robolinho%2520110%2520preis&amp;gl=DE&amp;hl=de&amp;pc=srp&amp;src=1">Anpassen</a><form action="https://consent.google.de/s" method="POST" style="display:inline;"><input name="gl" type="hidden" value="DE"/><input name="m" type="hidden" value="0"/><input name="pc" type="hidden" value="srp"/><input name="continue" type="hidden" value="https://www.google.de/search?q=AL-KO%20Robolinho%20110%20preis"/><input name="ca" type="hidden" value="r"/><input name="x" type="hidden" value="8"/><input name="v" type="hidden" value="cb.20210615-14-p0.de+FX+101"/><input name="t" type="hidden" value="ADw3F8gm29ymoJbw-6FRb_NfSx3E0sy9CQ:1624224939770"/><input name="hl" type="hidden" value="de"/><input name="src" type="hidden" value="1"/><input aria-label="In die Verwendung von Cookies und anderen Daten zu den beschriebenen Zwecken einwilligen" class="button" type="submit" value="Ich stimme zu"/></form></div></div><div class="footer"><form action="https://consent.google.de/ml" method="get"><select id="languageselect" name="hl"><option value="af">Afrikaans</option><option value="az">azərbaycan</option><option value="bs">bosanski</option><option value="ca">català</option><option value="cs">Čeština</option><option value="cy">Cymraeg</option><option value="da">Dansk</option><option selected="" value="de">Deutsch</option><option value="et">eesti</option><option value="en-GB">English (United Kingdom)</option><option value="en">English (United States)</option><option value="es">Español (España)</option><option value="es-419">Español (Latinoamérica)</option><option value="eu">euskara</option><option value="fil">Filipino</option><option value="fr-CA">Français (Canada)</option><option value="fr">Français (France)</option><option value="ga">Gaeilge</option><option value="gl">galego</option><option value="hr">Hrvatski</option><option value="id">Indonesia</option><option value="zu">isiZulu</option><option value="is">íslenska</option><option value="it">Italiano</option><option value="sw">Kiswahili</option><option value="lv">latviešu</option><option value="lt">lietuvių</option><option value="hu">magyar</option><option value="ms">Melayu</option><option value="nl">Nederlands</option><option value="no">norsk</option><option value="uz">o‘zbek</option><option value="pl">polski</option><option value="pt-BR">Português (Brasil)</option><option value="pt-PT">Português (Portugal)</option><option value="ro">română</option><option value="sq">shqip</option><option value="sk">Slovenčina</option><option value="sl">slovenščina</option><option value="sr-Latn">srpski (latinica)</option><option value="fi">Suomi</option><option value="sv">Svenska</option><option value="vi">Tiếng Việt</option><option value="tr">Türkçe</option><option value="el">Ελληνικά</option><option value="be">беларуская</option><option value="bg">български</option><option value="ky">кыргызча</option><option value="kk">қазақ тілі</option><option value="mk">македонски</option><option value="mn">монгол</option><option value="ru">Русский</option><option value="sr">српски</option><option value="uk">Українська</option><option value="ka">ქართული</option><option value="hy">հայերեն</option><option value="iw">עברית</option><option value="ur">اردو</option><option value="ar">العربية</option><option value="fa">فارسی</option><option value="am">አማርኛ</option><option value="ne">नेपाली</option><option value="mr">मराठी</option><option value="hi">हिन्दी</option><option value="as">অসমীয়া</option><option value="bn">বাংলা</option><option value="pa">ਪੰਜਾਬੀ</option><option value="gu">ગુજરાતી</option><option value="or">ଓଡ଼ିଆ</option><option value="ta">தமிழ்</option><option value="te">తెలుగు</option><option value="kn">ಕನ್ನಡ</option><option value="ml">മലയാളം</option><option value="si">සිංහල</option><option value="th">ไทย</option><option value="lo">ລາວ</option><option value="my">မြန်မာ</option><option value="km">ខ្មែរ</option><option value="ko">한국어</option><option value="ja">日本語</option><option value="zh-CN">简体中文</option><option value="zh-TW">繁體中文</option><option value="zh-HK">繁體中文 (香港)</option></select><input name="oldhl" type="hidden" value="de"/><input name="gl" type="hidden" value="DE"/><input name="m" type="hidden" value="0"/><input name="pc" type="hidden" value="srp"/><input name="continue" type="hidden" value="https://www.google.de/search?q=AL-KO%20Robolinho%20110%20preis"/><input name="src" type="hidden" value="1"/><input type="submit" value="Sprache ändern"/></form><a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=de&amp;utm_source=ucb">Datenschutzerklärung</a> <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=de&amp;utm_source=ucb">Nutzungsbedingungen</a></div></body></html>
[Finished in 0.539s]
```

I get the results page in German, "Bevor Sie zur Google Suche weitergehen" translates to "Before you move on to Google Search". And so on... this is the cookie notice you always get if you are not logged in and haven't accepted the cookies yet. How can I bypass that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when **scraping** websites.
Actually the library you are using, namely BeautifulSoup is built around the idea of parsing HTML code to extract data from it:

> Beautiful Soup transforms a complex HTML document into a complex tree of Python objects. [/beautiful-soup-4 doc](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#making-the-soup).

And that's fairly normal since it is used for web-scraping. However this is not really meant to interact with the page. For that, you will need a "real" browser. This can be automated with other tools better suited for the job like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) which allows you to interact with the page and even connect yourself to an account. Selenium uses a real browser and interact with it using an API.

Actually, I'm currently working on a project to reconnect to my ISP using Selenium. It can be a good example and starting point for you: [qt-autoconnect](https://github.com/0nyr/qt_autoconnect).

Just remember you can use both at the same time: using Selenium to accept cookies, get connected and retrieve the raw HTML then use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML!

As a conclusion, [here | Medium.com](https://medium.com/swlh/web-scraping-using-selenium-and-beautifulsoup-adfc8810240a) is a nice tutorial on how to use Selenium then BeautifulSoup to keep you going.

Have fun!